# Problema Eliminar datos de MySQL en una lista en Servlet

Tags: java, mysql, aplicación-web, servlets

Tengo, un problema al borrar un registro.
Esta es mi clase Consultas en donde borro a un usuario.

```
public static int Borrar(int id){
    int estado=0;
    try {
        Connection con = Consultas.getConnection();
        String sql = "call eliminar(?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        //e.getId cambia a id
        ps.setInt(1, id);

        estado = ps.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println("Lo borro");
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception d) {
        System.out.println("No lo borro");
        System.out.println(d.getMessage());
        System.out.println(d.getStackTrace());
    }
    return estado;
}
```

Este es el servlet en donde aparecen los usuarios y la opcion de eliminarlos.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"CSS/TABLES.css\">");
        out.println("<br><h1> ¡Hola Administrador! </h1>");

        List<Datos> lista = Consultas.getAllEmpleados();

        out.println("<table align='center'>");
        out.println("<tr>"
                + "<th> ID </th>"
                + "<th> Nombre </th>"
                + "<th> Correo </th>"
                + "<th> Usuario </th>"
                + "<th> Contraseña </th>"
                + "<th>  </th>"
                + "<th>  </th>"
                + "</tr>");
        for(Datos e:lista){
            out.println("<tr>"
                    + "<td>"+e.getId()+"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+e.getNombre()+"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+e.getCorreo()+"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+e.getUsuario()+"</td>"
                    + "<td>"+e.getContrasena()+"</td>"
                    + "<td><a href='EditarServlet? id="+e.getId()+"'>Editar</a></td>"
                    + "<td><a href='Borrar?  id1="+e.getId()+" '>Borrar</a></td>"
                    + "</tr>");
        }
        out.println("</table>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Y este es el Servlet de borrar, creo que el problema esta en el redireccionamiento de la lista a este servlet.

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        String eseid=request.getParameter("id1");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(eseid);
        System.out.println(id);
        Consultas.Borrar(id);
        response.sendRedirect("listausuarios");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Cuál es el mensaje de error?

Comment: Me manda esto: Advertencia:   StandardWrapperValve[Borrar]: Servlet.service() for servlet Borrar threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Comment: creo que podría ser el espacio que está en `"<td><a href='Borrar?  id1="+e.getId()+" '>Borrar</a></td>"`... debería ir `<a href='Borrar?id1="+e.getId()+" '>Borrar</a>`

Answer (score 1):

La excepción que se menciona en los comentarios indica que `request.getParameter("id1")` devuelve `null` y entonces ocurre la excepción al momento de intentar interpretar ese `id` como entero en `int id = Integer.parseInt(eseid)`.  Entonces parece ser que en la solicitud no está especificado el parámetro `id1`.

Revisando el código del servlet que genera el enlace noto que hay espacios entre el signo de interrogación `?` y los nombres de los parámetros en los enlaces que se generan:

```
+ "<td><a href='EditarServlet? id="+e.getId()+"'>Editar</a></td>"
+ "<td><a href='Borrar?  id1="+e.getId()+" '>Borrar</a></td>"
```

Por lo que me atrevo a decir que ese es el problema, intenta cambiar el código a:

```
+ "<td><a href='EditarServlet?id="+e.getId()+"'>Editar</a></td>"
+ "<td><a href='Borrar?id1="+e.getId()+" '>Borrar</a></td>"
```